# background image for each select element of a form select dropdown list

Tags: html, css

i have set style classes for each element of my form but setting the same background for a form dropdown is giving me an error.. you can see what the menu looks when its dropped down [image: what it looks like]
<sub>(source: [justni.com](http://justni.com/booking.png))</sub>

```
 .input_field{
    background-image:url('imgs/fieldbg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    width:465px;
    height:46px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-family:'Conv_lt_21019',Sans-Serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:22px;

}
select { -webkit-appearance: none; }

.input_field option{
    background-image:url('imgs/fieldbg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    width:465px;
    height:46px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-family:'Conv_lt_21019',Sans-Serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:22px;

}
```

And this is my html!

```
<select name="wave" class="input_field">
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">4</option>
<option value="4">5</option>
<option value="5">6</option>
<option value="6">7</option>
<option value="7">8</option>
<option value="8">9</option>
<option value="9">10</option>
<option value="10">11</option>
<option value="11">12</option>
<option value="12">13</option>
</select>
```

i would like to have an arrow, if not- the class repeated for each element of the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you expecting. But try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HbJvh/)